# sql-like interface for high performance python, but in the same process a singleton/object instead of a database?

Tags: python, sql, caching, redis, scientific-computing

I know this question might seem a bit odd, but I'm doing some high performance algorithmic code in python. It's extremely CPU bound with lots of graph traversals and very stateful. I'd like to setup some sort of relational database like interface for managing this state with all the usual guarantees that come with a proper RDBMS schema eg foreign keys, constraints, etc and not to mention sql queries.

Right now the state and the logic of the algorithm are fairly divorced. The state itself is more or less all but a relational database at this point, but instead of tables/rows it's a bunch of objects with a fairly complex web of relationships that are all but a relational (eg 1:1, 1:N, N:M, etc).

Ideally, I'd be able to use a standard ORM sort of technology to write out a bunch of schemas but instead of using redis or sqlite, it would just all be handled in the same python process as a singleton or the like so that it all stays in local memory

Comment: if you want high performance switch to C++, Rust, ..... The question is: you want an in-memory object oriented database? Use a normal database and use a RAM disk

Comment: i'm well aware but rewriting a codebase in cpp or rust isn't exactly a great use of eng time. and my concern is that in-memory is still too slow as it's still going to be doing a roundtrip to RAM, not to mention infra overhead, for what are mostly simple get/set operations.

Comment: you want to do it all in CPU cache?

Comment: i just want a better interface than a cobweb of objects and singletons like it is right now. Introducing a in-memory DB seems quite unnecessary if all I want is just something more ergonomic

Comment: eg imagine obj.do_something() has to perform obj_B.filter(A_id=obj.obj_A.id) or the sort. That's what it looks like right now

Comment: do you think adding a DB will increase your performance. The next question is how efficient have you implemented the current code?

Comment: you aren't listening to my question.

Comment: implement a simple SQL parser and implement the simple selections, use a few regex with capture groups. You don't need a full SQL syntax parser.

Comment: If you're doing `lots graph traversals and very stateful` you might want to consider using https://redisgraph.io